# Fifo vs Client/Server

Tags: c, linux, bash, sockets, fifo

I'm new here... I want to premise I don't want the solution to my problem but I need to understand which is difference between a client/server program and a FIFO reader/writer program... I explain better...

I have to do a project for an exam. The purpose of the project is "define script Bash and C programs to correct automatically the examination tasks."

The professor ask to me to write some Bash scripts to take the examination tasks, check them and, for each task, write the scores on a file. Everything is clear until now.

Then the professor ask 4 C program and I do not understand anything anymore. I translate in English exactly what is written in the project specification:

> **fifo_reader**
> It's a C client that read the content of a FIFO and print it on the stdout
> Take as parameter (as argument from command line) the Fifo's name
>
> **fifo_writer**
>
> It's a C client that write the content of the stdin in a FIFO
> Take as parameter (as argument from command line) the Fifo's name
>
> **network_server_echo**
>
> It's a C server that listen to a net port (TCP or UDP) (number of the port and backlog value passed as argument from command line) and:
>
> 1. read the strings on the input stream
> 2. write the string that has been read on the correspondent output stream
>
> **network_client_echo**
>
> It's the client version of the network_server_echo

Here what i do not understand:
A fifo writer/reader is not like a client/server application with socket? So, the professor is asking us the same thing in two different ways? But when the professor talk about fifo reader/writer, he define both them client... Perhaps I have not understood what the professor is really asking us....Can anyone help me plz?

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have fully understand the question :-)

It seems to me that the work should be done in two different ways. A `named fifo` is not a `fifo` is not a `socket`. So you will learn how to access the different unix ways to communicate. And it makes sense to look in the differences of all these approaches I think.

Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

Great! Youre understand right. The FIFO file (often called as `named pipes`) works locally (on UNIX like systems), while the `sockets` based solution are for networking.

However, in the Windows, the `named pipes` works over the (microsoft) network too, so you can open a named pipe FIFO on one computer and access it from the second one. This doen't works in UNIX-like systems.